# Как сделать show/hide  анимацию?

Tags: android, анимация, java

Доброго времени суток!
Я долго думал, пробовал и искал (видимо плохо искал), но так и не знаю как сделать реализацию вот такой вот анимации. Вопрос: как сделать такую анимацию?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Android. Выпадающий список (Spinner) с индикатором загрузки](http://habrahabr.ru/post/151285/)

Answer (score 2):

`AutoCompleteTextView` - можно кастомизировать таким образом. Давеча делал.

Comment: каждый день такое делаем =)

Comment: Это интересно, а можно пример, и меня интересует не просто чтобы там текст был, а чтобы там можно было разместить любой View

Comment: в примере все это есть, вью можно переопределить в адаптере или посмотреть как делается первый элемент и загрузкой и сделать аналогично любые

Answer (score 0):

Ну а я бы посоветовал проявить олдскульность и написать свою класс-обертку.
У всех компонентов есть, как минимум, метод PaintComponent(), который в наследнике этого компонента можно перезаписать.
В этом методе, основываясь на разницу во времени старта и System.currentTimeMillis() уже рисовать анимацию. Если покруче - то даблбуфферед и someComponent.setStyle(), с перезаписью соответствующего стиля.

Звучит и кажется сложным, сейчас новое поколение меня андроидами закидает, но это выгоднее, чем использовать сторонние монструозные пакеты, ИМХО.